# Passing php variable to window.location

Tags: javascript, php

I use the following code for my sumbit to reddit button.

```
onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=<?php echo $url?>';
```

but the above won't work for cases where there a `'` in `$url`

```
onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=http://vinejar.com/96-Don't-be-this-guy.html';
```

It is necessary to get `$url` there so the following won't help.

```
onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could encode your $url,for example:

```
onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=<?php echo urlencode($url) ?>';
```